# iPhone SDK 4 available only for Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am about to download SDK 4 for iPhone development but on their website the download is for Mac OS X Snow Leopard. The current version on my Mac is Mac OS X Leopard 10.5.8... Won't I be able to install the SDK without upgrading to Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Comment: An upgrade is $29 and worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, Xcode 3.2.3 with iPhone SDK (iOS4) is a Snow Leopard install only, as far as I see.

Answer (score 1):

I think that iOS4 is bringing a lot more feature parity between itself and snow leopard. So I don't think apple will be releasing this download for leopard any time soon. Though check the [developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/discussionForum.action) to make sure.

Sadly though you may need to upgrade if you want to continue to develop for iOS4.